# Improving active record queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following queries, i know it looks very bad.

Note: I added them to instance variables because i will use them inside highcharts js library so each instance variable will represent a single column/bar/line inside highcharts js

tickets_controller.rb

```
def priorities_chart
    priority_base = Ticket.includes(:priority)
    @high_tickets_counter = priority_base.where(priorities: {name: 'High'}).count
    @medium_tickets_counter = priority_base.where(priorities: {name: 'Medium'}).count
    @low_tickets_counter = priority_base.where(priorities: {name: 'Low'}).count
  end

  def statuses_chart
    status_base = Ticket.includes({ticket_statuses: :status})
    @open_tickets_counter = status_base.where(statuses: {ticket_status: 'Open'}).count
    @in_progress_tickets_counter = status_base.where(statuses: {ticket_status: 'In Progress'}).count
    @pending_tickets_counter = status_base.where(statuses: {ticket_status: 'Pending'}).count
    @solved_tickets_counter = status_base.where(statuses: {ticket_status: 'Solved'}).count
    @closed_tickets_counter = status_base.where(statuses: {ticket_status: 'Closed'}).count
  end

  def subjects_chart
    subject_base = Ticket.includes({student: :subjects})
    @subject_1_counter = subject_base.where(subjects: {subject_title: 'Subject 1'}).count
    @subject_2_counter = subject_base.where(subjects: {subject_title: 'Subject 2'}).count
    @subject_3_counter = subject_base.where(subjects: {subject_title: 'Subject 3'}).count
    @subject_4_counter = subject_base.where(subjects: {subject_title: 'Subject 4'}).count
    @subject_5_counter = subject_base.where(subjects: {subject_title: 'Subject 5'}).count
  end
```

I need to improve this ugly look and achieving the following:

1- what if i have another subjects with different names or more than 10 subjects , i need a query to handle this without specifying the subject title as i am doing here.

2- is there a better way to write priorities_chart and statuses_chart ?

Answer (score 0):

i've tried to translate my working example to your case.

```
 def subjects_chart
   search = [ 'Subject 1', 'Subject 2', 'Subject 3', 'Subject 4' ]
   subject_base = Ticket.includes({student: :subjects})
   @subject_counter = 
     subject_base.where( subjects: { subject_title: search } ).
     group( 'tickets.id' ).
     count( 'subjects.id' )
```

end

is this working?

Comment: I haven't tried this yet , but for the subjects chart , it still specified what it should render and i am using a sample data not a real one , so when the subject title changes the chart will not work any more also what if its more than four , so everything is limited here i need to change that.

Comment: when the subject changes and there is no need to search for, group by subject. i just tried to give you an idea. all the best.

Comment: not working as i expected, also it only have one variable, i cannot use it for chart